# Ways method to protect members profile edit pages?

Tags: members, url, member-details

Just looking at finding the best ways ways to protect member profile editing pages.

I have members profiles set up under a template structure such as

```
members/profile/{member_id}/sub-page
```

Thats is fine, all these pages are public. I do however show, on the members own profile page, a link to edit their details. This is displayed via the conditional

```
{if segment_3 == logged_in_member_id}                   
   <a href="{path='members/account/{member_id}/profile'}">Edit Your Account</a>
{/if}
```

I then have the account edit pages such as (this is actually one template using switchee)

```
members/account/{member_id}/profile
members/account/{member_id}/password
members/account/{member_id}/avatar
members/account/{member_id}/notifications
```

But these pages should ***only*** be viewed by the logged in member, which at the moment is easily bypassed via just changing the `member_id` in the URL.

So what would be the best way to protect these pages, so if someone did try and change the `member_id` in the URL, they would not be able to access other users pages.

Thanks!

(And whilst I'm on this subject, is is possible to use the `username` in the URL as opposed to the `member_id` ?

Many thanks!

Comment: What add-on are you using to allow editing of member profiles in templates?

Comment: A mix of User and Freemember.

Comment: I updated my answer with a second option that is specific to those add-ons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1: Use Conditionals**

In your `members/account/{member_id}/profile` template (or portion of your template, since you're using Switchee), you can wrap the profile-editing form and other content in a conditional to make sure the user can only edit their own profile. All other users can be shown alternate content (an error message  in this example):

```
{if segment_3 == logged_in_member_id}                   
   {!-- Profile-editing template stuff here --}
{/if}

{if segment_3 != logged_in_member_id}                   
   <div class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</div>
{/if}
```

**Option 2: Avoid segment variables and rely on your add-on(s)**

Another option, since you are using User and/or FreeMember, is to rely on their profile editing tags to take care of locking down the forms so that users cannot edit other user's profiles.

The FreeMember [update_profile](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/wiki/Update-Profile-Tag) tag is automatically tied to the currently logged in user.

Or with User's [edit](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/) tag you should be able to specify the [member_id parameter](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/#member_id) to be `{logged_in_member_id}` to limit the edit form only to the currently logged in user.

With either of these two add-on-specific methods you don't need to rely on the `member_id` being in the URL and so you avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: You could just use the second conditional like so. `{if segment_3 != logged_in_member_id}{redirect="unauthorized"}{/if}`

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, I was thinking of something along these lines, but wasn't sure if there was a better / method. Will give it a go!

Comment: Thanks for the update with option two. This is what I have working now, and it seems pretty robust. Every time I change a member I'd in the URL, it just stays on my edit pages! Thumbs up! Great stuff. Just what I wanted and no extra mark up! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way is to use a conditional to check the logged in member ID against the member id in the url. As mentioned in Alex Kendrick's answer.

```
{if logged_in_member_id == segment_3}
    stuff only visible to member
{/if}
```